# Pass data between activities Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know if there is a way to pass a class object, which can't implement serializable interface between 2 android activities.
I know that to pass data using intent you have to implement serializable interface, but unfortunately I can't do this, any idea?

```
public class ContactMongo implements Serializable{
private DB collection;
public ContactMongo() 
{ }

}
```

DB doesn't implement serializable, so I can't perform intent.putExtra();

Comment: provide the class you want to pass

Comment: By "class object", do you mean an instance of `Class`? If so, then pass something that identifies what class you want the other activity to use.

Comment: Y you can't use it ? or otherwise use **Parcelable.**

Comment: You are either trying to pass something you shouldn't pass to another activity (like file descriptors), or you can write a wrapper class that implements `Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a service, but you haven't told us anything about what you're trying to pass, so I guess you want to use ugly hacks.

There is such an ugly hack available, but it'll quickly get out of control (especially if you cannot even search on this topic by yourself) - you can extend your `Application` class and use its methods to pass data between activities. Generally, it should be avoided and other ways to pass data and let activities communicate should be used (like extracting the data from the object you want to pass).

Hope this helps you, comment if you have any questions (I'll update my answer with better solution if you give more information on what you're trying to do)

Answer (score -1):

You need to send an intent with whatever you want to pass.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Object object;
    intent.putExtra("nameforyourobject", object);
    startActivity(intent);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: His class doesn't implement `Serializable` nor `Parcelable` nor is one of the supported data types for `putExtra()`. And he tells he cannot implement `Serializable`